# How to detect UIButton pressing state?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uibutton

I want to call method continuously when button pressing. I can detect UIButton pressed state using touchup inside or other similar action. So how can I detect UIButton pressing state?

Comment: Pressing state like what?

Comment: If you want to change the Button's background image , I guess it would be Highlighted state

Comment: @Hemal check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11181340/keeping-a-uibutton-pressedstate-selected-highlighted-until-another-button-is-p

Comment: No when button pressing I want to move another view continuously. When release button from pressing I want to stop it.

Comment: You can fire one method on touchDown, and detect the end of touching in touchUp.

Comment: @rdelmar I think your solution is the best one. Thanks.

Comment: Or you can use tags.

Comment: Reasons for down-voting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I did:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressRecordButton:)];
[self.view.recordBtn addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
UIButton *recordButton = self.view.recordBtn;
[recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(beginTouchRecord:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(endTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[recordButton addTarget:self action:@selector(endTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get action method for this state only

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIControlEvents) {
UIControlEventTouchDown           = 1 <<  0,      // on all touch downs
UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat     = 1 <<  1,      // on multiple touchdowns (tap count > 1)
UIControlEventTouchDragInside     = 1 <<  2,
UIControlEventTouchDragOutside    = 1 <<  3,
UIControlEventTouchDragEnter      = 1 <<  4,
UIControlEventTouchDragExit       = 1 <<  5,
UIControlEventTouchUpInside       = 1 <<  6,
UIControlEventTouchUpOutside      = 1 <<  7,
UIControlEventTouchCancel         = 1 <<  8,

UIControlEventValueChanged        = 1 << 12,     // sliders, etc.

UIControlEventEditingDidBegin     = 1 << 16,     // UITextField
UIControlEventEditingChanged      = 1 << 17,
UIControlEventEditingDidEnd       = 1 << 18,
UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,     // 'return key' ending editing

UIControlEventAllTouchEvents      = 0x00000FFF,  // for touch events
UIControlEventAllEditingEvents    = 0x000F0000,  // for UITextField
UIControlEventApplicationReserved = 0x0F000000,  // range available for application use
UIControlEventSystemReserved      = 0xF0000000,  // range reserved for internal framework use
UIControlEventAllEvents           = 0xFFFFFFFF
};
```